# Generate all possible permutations in julia

Tags: binary, julia

What I am trying to do is generate all possible permutations of 1 and 0 given a particular sample size. For instance with a sample of n=8 I would like the m = 2^8 = 256 possible permutations, i.e:

[image]

I have been doing this in R, but it is very slow. Is there a quick way to do this in the Julia programming language?

Comment: I think that "permutation" is not the word you're looking for here since there are 8! = 40320 permutations of 8 objects. You're seem to be looking for the number of subsets of 8 distinct objects, without ordering, which is 2^8 = 256.

Answer (score 8):

These are just the numbers from `0` to `2^k-1`, written in binary.

```
# Strings
k=8
[ bin(n,k) for n in 0:2^k-1 ]

# Arrays
[ [ bit == '1' ? 1 : 0 for bit in bin(n,k) ] for n in 0:2^k-1 ]
```